# Why does wp_links still exist in the db schema?

Tags: database, links, core

I understand that *links* used to be a big thing when Wordpress came out and during the blog rise, but the link feature is so underused nowadays that [as of version 3.5 it is hidden by default](http://codex.wordpress.org/Links_Manager) (thus greatly discouraging its usage).

Moreover, I don't see any reason why Links themselves shouldn't be a **Custom Post Type** as it would be much more consistent with the approach Wordpress has taken in its data architecture.

Is **backwards compatibility** the only reason why such basic things as the db schema aren't touched? Or is there some other reason I am not grasping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answer yourself pretty much - "hidden" does not mean removed. It still works.

And yes, the reason would be backwards compatibility which is considered absolute priority in WP. See [#21307 Remove Link Manager from core](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21307) for context and discussion.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful link! I understand that hidden doesn't mean removed, but I was wondering why the information architecture for this specific feature (which, though not removed, it's quite obsolete or niche) wasn't reworked into CPTs. And from what I read in that discussion, I understand that they are looking to remove the feature completely but it was closed 8 months ago without a follow-up…?

Comment: @Sunyatasattva things move quite slowly in WP development, with backwards compat considerations it will probably take years to completely wash it out of core